# Hovering both elements of a nest

Tags: css, html, hover, nested

By using pure CSS (no JavaScript), how can I make it that **only when** I hover **both** .a and .b, **both** .a and .b get red? (This can be interpreted as "when I hover .b, .a gets red")

HTML:

```
<div class="a">AAAAA<div class="b">BBBBB</div></div>
```

Some CSS desperate failed attempts:

```
.b:hover .a {color: red;}
.a.b:hover {color: red;}
.b:hover + .a {color: red;}
.b:hover ~ .a {color: red;}
.b:hover < .a {color: red;}
```

But it feels that anything that could select a parent element won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<` doesn't exist and `+` as `~` are adjacent sibling selectors, but just for subsequent elements.

Basically, you can't do that with pure CSS because it doesn't exist something like a parent selector, which you would need to specify *if `.b` is hovered style also parent element*.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your page

```
<style type="text/css">
    .a:hover{
   background-color:red;
}
    </style>
```

hope this works for you.